# Cocoa Touch JSON Handling

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I've been looking for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution.

I am trying to format a JSON object that is being held in an NSData *receivedData.

The format of the JSON is:

[
{
"name":"Stephen",
"nickname":"Bob"
},
{
"name":"Rob",
"nickname":"Mike"
},
{
"name":"Arya",
"nickname":"Jane"
}
]

Normally I would use "NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:" of the NSDictionary. Then I would normally take the root of the JSON (in this case it would be something like "People":) and create the array from that root object. However as you can see this response is simply an array without a root object. I'm not sure how to handle this. The end goal is to have an array of Person objects, populated with the data in the JSON.

Edit: I would also like to add that I want to keep it native without third party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK for anyone reading this. I just figured it out. Instead of formatting the initial NSData into a dictionary, you put that straight into an array. Then create a dictionary for each object in the array. Like so:

```
NSArray *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary* json = [responseArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"nickname"]);
```